# How to turn on exceptions for an invalid dictionary lookup in Django templates?

Tags: django

When the Django template system encounters an invalid dictionary lookup it silently replaced by an empty string.

For specific dictionary lookups though, I'd like Django to raise an exception to help with debugging.

Assuming a dictionary like this:

```py
colors = {"red": 1, "green 2, "blue": 3}
```

An exception should be raised here:

```
{{ colors.orange }}
```

How can I force the Django template system to raise an exception when it encounters an invalid dictionary lookup?

Comment: You don't, or not easily. You can apply some "trick" however, basically abusing the system a bit.l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django template engine is not really made to do that. But we can "hack" it in. Indeed, we can define our own `InvalidVarException` which will for example log, or raise an exception:

```
import inspect
import logging
from itertools import islice

from django.template.base import FilterExpression

UNKNOWN = object()
MISSING = object()


def all_in_stack(type_filter, var_name='self'):
    for item in islice(inspect.stack(), 1):
        obj = item.frame.f_locals.get(var_name, MISSING)
        if obj is not MISSING and isinstance(obj, type_filter):
            yield obj


def look_in_stack(type_filter, var_name='self'):
    for item in all_in_stack(type_filter=type_filter, var_name=var_name):
        return item
    return MISSING


def or_unknown(
    f, *args, _unknown=UNKNOWN, _exception_type_filter=BaseException, **kwargs
):
    try:
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        if result is MISSING:
            return _unknown
        return result
    except _exception_type_filter:
        return _unknown


def get_request_from_stack(type_filter: HttpRequest, var_name='request'):
    return look_in_stack(type_filter=type_filter, var_name=var_name)


def get_template_node_from_stack(var_name='self'):
    return look_in_stack(Node, var_name=var_name)


def get_template_location_from_stack(var_name='self'):
    return get_node_file_loc(get_template_node_from_stack(var_name=var_name))


logger = logging.getLogger('templates')


class InvalidVarException(str):
    already = set()

    def __mod__(self, missing, *args, **kwargs):
        missing_str = or_unknown(str, missing)
        request = or_unknown(get_request_from_stack)
        path = request.path
        full_path = request.get_full_path()
        loc = or_unknown(get_template_location_from_stack)
        key = (path, loc, missing_str)
        show = key not in self.already
        if show:
            self.already.add(key)
            try:
                message = f'Missing variable {{{{ {missing_str} }}}} at {loc} for path {full_path}'
                logger.error(message)
            except:
                pass
        return self

    def __bool__(self):
        return True

    def __contains__(self, search):
        return '%s' in search or super().__contains__(search)


def is_simple_constant(expr):
    if not expr.is_var and (not expr.filters):
        return expr.var
```

and then we can register the `InvalidVarException` as `string_if_invalid` option:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # …
        'OPTIONS': {
            # …
            'string_if_invalid': InvalidVarException(),
            # …
        },
    },
]
```

the idea is that Django normally renders the `string_if_invalid` if it can not find the variable, which thus turns the engine silent. But here we use a trick to let the string be formatted, and use that to look up the template and variable, and then log the result.

Answer (score 1):

You cant directly raise an exception from django's template system. It is designed to fail silently.But what you can do is to define a custom template tag used to validate a dictionary and will raise exception if missing keys (invalid lookup).